# Why we don't add try catch when using New operation

Tags: c#, exception

,In C# and C++ , no one uses exception handling for `new` operator ,what's the reason ?
Is it guaranteed that the call will always be successful  ?

Comment: Couldn't an out of memory exception be generated?  No guarantee of success at all.  I believe the test is whether the variable is assigned a value or still NULL.

Comment: It can throw `OutOfMemoryException`, but handling it is hard. So I leave it to the top level handler and pray.

Comment: So the exception would keep bubbling up to a higher level to catch that the call failed, or become a fatal error if unhandled up the chain.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Not even in C++.  That said, even there it's only occasionally appropriate to handle the case right away (just as in C#).  Often when you're in that position there isn't much you can do to come back from it and you just need to let the exception bubble up to a high level where it can be logged, things can be cleaned up, and you can gracefully crash.

Comment: Actually it's possible to turn off the exception throwing for `new` in C++, and make it return null instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that the call will always be successful ?

No, this is not guaranteed.

That being said, in general, it's only a good idea to handle exceptions that you can actually do something about.  *By convention*, it's a good idea to design your object construction in such a way to minimize exceptions.  That being said, this is not always possible, and many cases, calling `new Foo()` can easily throw an exception you may want to catch.

For example, if you try to do this, you're guaranteed to raise an exception, as this is longer than the maximum number of items allowed in an array in a single dimension (even with `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` set):

```
var willCauseException = new double[int.MaxValue];
```

Comment: It's too bad that the major languages don't really provide an idiom for code to act upon exceptions that it can't possibly resolve.  Catch-and-rethrow kinda sorta works, but it's icky.  It would be nicer if `catch` could be reserved for code that has a chance of resolving an exception, and some other block type (e.e. either `fault(Exception ex)` or `finally(Exception ex)` could be used for code which knows it won't be able to resolve an exception but needs to take action based upon it anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

Well, *no one* is a strong expression. In fact, industrial-level applications should check for these errors. But this does not mean that errors should be checked *everywhere*.

Attempting to create an object with `new` can raise an `std::bad_alloc` or an `OutOfMemoryException` (depending on your language), in addition to any memory that the constructor itself might raise. But if you caught this exception, what would you do with it? The right thing to do is to catch these exceptions in a centralised place (probably at the main loop of the application) and deal with them there. Every time you see one of those messages saying "You are running out of memory: save your current job and exit the application", or the like, it means that one of these exceptions has been caught and dealt with (usually by releasing an emergency memory block to allow for graceful termination and then warning the user).

Exception management does not consist on writing `try-catch` blocks everywhere; they must exist only in the right places, and the rest of the code must be written taking into account that exceptions may happen and the system state must be left always in a recoverable state.